# is there any function similar to skipLocationchange in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

```
skipLocationchange : true
```

prevents from storing path in history in **angular 2+**,

likewise is there any similar function in **jquery**?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Prevent a page load going into browser history?

Comment: yes... the page name should not be stored in browser history....

Comment: Try the search and you'll find a few similar questions that explain what's possible and what's not. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=don%27t+add+page+to+browser+history